# BeautifulSoup misinterprets <area> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautifulsoup to extract metadata from tobacco documents like this: http://legacy.library.ucsf.edu/tid/bxf03e00/xml

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(input)
meta_data = soup.document.metadata
```

This correctly identifies all tags except for

```
<area>GEE,ED/OFFICE; N408</area>
```

Beautiful soup identifies the area tag as two separate tags:

- An area tag `<area></area>` that is empty.
- An empty tag with the content `GEE,ED/OFFICE; N408`

Does this bug occur because `<area>` is an HTML tag? 
And how do I get beautiful soup to correctly identify `GEE,ED/OFFICE; N408` as the content of the `<area>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The central issue is that you haven't told `bs4` that it's parsing XML.  It *assumes* HTML - print it out and notice how the parser wraps everything in `<html><body>` tags.

```
import requests

req = requests.get('http://legacy.library.ucsf.edu/tid/bxf03e00/xml')

doc = req.text

BeautifulSoup(doc).find('area')
Out[79]: <area></area>
```

Tell it that it should parse it as XML (it will use `lxml` to do so, you need to have that dependency installed or this will fail):

```
BeautifulSoup(doc,'xml').find('area')
Out[80]: <area>GEE,ED/OFFICE; N408</area>
```